# sqlbulkcopy - When converting string to DateTime

Tags: c#, excel, csv, datetime, sqlbulkcopy

I am using this code to insert a csv file to my database:

```
    private void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable csvFileData)
    {
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
            {
                s.DestinationTableName = "tablename";
                foreach (var column in csvFileData.Columns)
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);
            }
        }
    }


    private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
    {
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
            {
                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                foreach (string column in colFields)
                {
                    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                    csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);

                }
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();

                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }
                    }
                    csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                }
            }
        }
```

My database has temporary data in it. To test this code I copied fields with headers from SQL server and pasted it into an excel file. I then saved the excel file to csv and ran the code. It adds the data from the csv to the database perfectly!

I then tried running a csv file with similar values to my original csv file and its giving me a 'String to DateTime' Exception. So I know something is up with the Dates and I know that the excel columns are in value of 'Date'.

Im really scratching my head with this one. Any good way to parse columns with dates?

Comment: You'll need to show us the full text of the exception, as well as the string representation of the date you're trying to import. Note that simply setting a column to `Date` in excel does not mean anything in terms of the CSV file, in which there are no types. It's likely excel is outputting a format that's not compatible with the format you're trying to read as (for example excel outputs MM/dd/yyyy and your application is expecting dd/MM/yyyy).

Comment: The full exception is: InnerException: When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object. Make sure your method arguments are in the right format.      My Dates: 30/11/2015

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing a few issues with your code that could cause you some trouble.

1. There is no schema validation of the CSV file. You simple take any given CSV file and attempt to write it to the server using whatever column headers it has.
2. When you create a `DataColumn` instance, the default column type will be `System.String`. This is probably causing your date issues.
3. I don't see any transformation of the data in the CSV file. If one of the fields in your database table is a `datetime` and you are attempting to bulk insert a `System.String` column you are going to run into issues.

My suggestions would be the following:

1. Perform schema validation on the CSV file so you know you are getting the input you expect. This is two-fold: ensure the data is in the expected format and ensure the expected column headers exist.
2. For the table that you bulk insert, create column types that are appropriate for your SQL tables. Use the overload of the `DataColumn` constructor where you specify the column data type: `new DataColumn("Name", typeof(DateTime))`
3. Take the data you **E**xtracted from the CSV (all as strings) and **T**ransform it into the required format, then **L**oad it.

The operation you are doing is a very basic [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load). It appears you have the Extract and Load portion working, the thing you are missing is the Transform component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ill reply with an update as soon as I make my changes.

Comment: Ive done what you have asked for: new DataColumn("DateCreated", typeof(DateTime)), new DataColumn("DateOrdered", typeof(DateTime)). This is waht my new values look, there are more but ive highlighted these. The new Exception I get is -------"The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.Couldn't store <DateCreated> in DateCreated Column.  Expected type is DateTime."

Comment: Part of the transformation component I talked about means that you need to write code that parses those strings into valid dates using the date method: `TryParse`

Comment: Ive tried something like this to no avail.------------            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                row["DateCreated"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateCreated"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                row["DateOrdered"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateOrdered"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                row["RecordAddedDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row["RecordAddedDate"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            } I couldent seem to get the TryParse thing to work